# Typesense query weights with instantsearch.js adapter

Tags: instantsearch.js, typesense

I'm looking to weight different fields in my typesense search ranking. With a typesense client, my understanding is that I'd use [query_by_weights](https://typesense.org/docs/0.19.0/api/documents.html#arguments).

But I'm using the react instantsearch adapter. How do I set query weights there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `query_by_weights` inside `additionalSearchParameters` when you instantiate the typesense-instantsearch-adapter.